# Limit of a recursive sequence derived from a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, continuity

I spent the past couple of days trying to crack this, but with no luck.

I would really apreaciate any and all thoughts and ideas about this one.

> (a) Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow[a, b]$ be a differentiable function and let $t \in[a, b]$ and consider the sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by the following recursive formula:
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> x_{1}=t \\
> x_{n+1}=f\left(x_{n}\right) \quad \forall n \geq 1
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> Suppose also that there exists a point $\alpha \in[a, b]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$. Prove that if there exists a $0 \leq q<1$ such that $\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right| \leq q$ for every $x \in[a, b]$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}=\alpha$.

[Trascribed from this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttd5q.jpg)

So far I've tried using the fact that f is differentiable and therefore continuous and then play around with the definitions of the limits but that didn't really help.

Also tried using lagrange's theorom on the interval [X(n), α] to show that |X(n+1) - α| <= |X(n) - α| (tried this because of a reccomendation from a friend who takes the same course) but that didn't get me anywhere either.

Basically all I managed so far was to prove the case where q = 0 (which is pretty trivial), but I still can't figure out a way to prove the other case for q > 0.

Thanks in advance to all those who share their wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha=f(\alpha)$, we can write

$|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=|f(x_n)-f(\alpha)|$.

Because $f$ is differentiable, there exists $c_n$ between $x_n$ and $\alpha$ such that
$f(x_n)-f(\alpha)=f'(c_n)(x_n-\alpha)$. Therefore,

$|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=|f'(c_n)||x_n-\alpha|\leq q|x_n-\alpha|$.

Applying the same argument to $|x_n-\alpha|, |x_{n-1}-\alpha|,\ldots, |x_2-\alpha|$, we eventually obtain

$|x_{n+1}-\alpha|\leq q^n|x_1-\alpha|$.

Since $0\leq q<1$, it follows that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=0$.

Comment: thank you very much!